# ATI AMD Radeon 6670M 2GB Dual External monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, hp-pavilion

I have HP Pavilion dv7 BeatsAudo model: dv7-6b with following specifications:

> CPU: Intel i7-2670QM ( Quad Core ) 8 CPU's @ 2.2Ghz
>   RAM: 8GB @ 1066
>   GPU: ATI Radeon HD 6770M 1GB

Notebook has two slots: HDMI and VGA

On my VGA i have an external monitor 24" Samsung, any idea if my notebook could support a second external monitor as well. I do a lot of development work, i havent got a second monitor to test it yes but i know there can be problems.

I would like to have a monitor connected on my VGA and on my HDMI so two external monitors and notebooks monitor.

Would this be viable ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double check,  but I believe this Radeon has the [Eyefinity feature](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/Pages/eyefinity.aspx), and so it should support up to 5 displays.